# Add text from form at the end of text/line

Tags: javascript, html

I have a really stupid question i guess. Can u give me a hint how can i do that:

I want to write a little app that will help me with my work.

I have to generate a link which looks something like this:

MYSITE.COM/id_search?1234,1235,1236...

basically I have to paste these numbers after id_search?

I do it in notepad, and sometimes I paste it wrong etc so I have to do it all over again.

is it possible to write a html doc that help me with that? i mean i put a number in a form press submit and this number appears at the end of line

MYSITE.COM/id_search?1234,1235,1236,

sorry for my english ;) i would be glad if you give me a hint where can i start, i know probably its really easy but i don't know where to start ;)

Comment: It would be nice if you can try to clarify in a better way, as it stands, the question is not understandable. Can you please clarify again, like Step by Step basis?

Comment: I want to put a number from form as a text in document.

1. I put a number in a form.
2. Press submit.
3. Number appears as a text on site.
4. When i put a new number in a form and press submit it appers as a next number

1234,1235,1236,(new number shows here)

Comment: Are you using any backend programming language like PHP?

Comment: No, im not using it. Is it possible by js or jquery? i don't want to save those numbers anywhere just copy it.

Comment: It is possible. Wait.